# Is it possible to compile node.js 4 or 6 for a 32 bits mac?

Tags: node.js, macos

I was searching for a **32 bits** version of node.js and notices that the last darwin x86 version is on the `0.x.x` folders.

Is it possible to compile from source onto the 32 bits or it is just not supported?

I'm running OSX 10.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum required OS X version was bumped to 10.7 back in April 26 with [204f3a8a0b](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/204f3a8a0b4625f2b13a2104c2f2430329dee7fa), which was incorporated only into node v6.0.0, so it is not possible to build v6.0.0 on OS X 10.6 unless you modify `common.gypi` and build it yourself. Even then you're on your own since it is no longer supported.

node v5.x and earlier still support building on OS X 10.5+ without any changes, but you'll still need to build it yourself.